# How can I use xsd:any with a namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd

I need a clarification on one of scenarios of `<xsd:any>`.

What if `namespace` attribute's value is `##any` and the attribute `processContents` doesn't exist (the default value is `strict`)?

What will be the case here, Should the processor validate the elements against any schemes?

Example for clarification. Here's XSD section:

```
......
<xsd:complexType name="reservedType"> <!-- a declaration for an element `reserved` -->
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:any namespace="##any"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
..........
```

And here's the XML:

```
<c:reserved>
<message xmlns="unknown_schema">
 <msg>Hello</msg>
</message>
</c:reserved>
```

Whenever I try to validate this XML against the above schema, I get:

```
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'message'.
```

How this come, and the namespace is `##any`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default processing model for `xsd:any` *is strict*. So yes, you will have to set this element to `lax` or `skip`:

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Please refer to [Section 3.10.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-openness) of the XML Schema specification. See the table just below, on "Wildcard Schema Components", in particular the process contents attribute.